# Usar WSGI con python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, apache

Necesito ayuda para poner a funcionar una aplicación con *Django 1.8* y *Python 3.5* en un servidor Ubuntu.

(Edición: Están instalados `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` y habilitado el `a2enmod wsgi`)

El código está ubicado en `/var/www/html/ripso2/codigo` (por motivos amenos a mí la carpeta de los archivos media es: `/var/www/html/ripso2/media`)

**La estructura de directorios es la siguiente:**

```
├── agenda
│   └── templates
├── capacitaciones
│   └── templates
├── configuracion
│   └── templates
├── consultas
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── agenda
│   │   ├── capacitaciones
│   │   ├── epp
│   │   ├── gestion_riesgos
│   │   ├── mantenimiento_equipos
│   │   ├── novedades
│   │   └── rh
│   └── views
├── copasst
│   └── templates
├── cronograma
│   └── templates
├── __datos_iniciales__
│   ├── csv
│   ├── json
│   └── sql
├── epp
│   └── templates
├── estadisticas
│   ├── templates
│   └── views
├── general
│   └── templates
├── gestion_riesgo
│   └── templates
├── gestion_salud
│   ├── templates
│   └── views
├── gestion_usuarios
│   └── templates
├── indicadores
│   ├── templates
│   └── views
├── mantenimiento_equipo
│   └── templates
├── matriz_legal
│   └── templates
├── novedades
│   └── templates
├── phva
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── actuar
│   │   ├── hacer
│   │   ├── planear
│   │   └── verificar
│   └── views
├── recurso_humano
│   ├── templates
│   └── views
├── ripso
    └── settings.py
    └── urls.py
    └── **wsgi.py**
├── seguimiento_cliente
│   └── templates
├── static
│   ├── ...
└── templates
    ├── menus
    └── publico
└── .gitignore
└── Readme.md
└── **django.wsgi**
└── manage.py
└── requirements.txt
```

El archivo `wsgi.py` es el siguiente:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ripso.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

El archivo `django.wsgi` es el siguiente:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/var/www/html/ripso2/codigo')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'ripso.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

El virtualhost en `etc/apache2/sites-available` es:

```
<VirtualHost midominio:80>
        ServerName pruebasoftware.midominio
        ServerAdmin aaaa@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ripso2/codigo

        #WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/ripso2/codigo/django.wsgi
        Alias /static/ /var/www/html/ripso2/codigo/static/

        <Directory /var/www/html/ripso2/codigo>
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/html/ripso2/codigo/static>
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/pruebasoftware.midominio-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/pruebasoftware.midominio-access.log co$

</VirtualHost>
```

Mi situación actual es que por ahora sólo se muestra una estructura de directorios (por lo que no he incluido el WSGI), sin embargo verifiqué (y está bien) la conexión con la base de datos y `pgadmin`.

[image: dirs]

He seguido guías pero creo que no he seguido la correcta porque con éstas ni siquiera me deja reiniciar Apache. Por favor ayúdenme a poder ejecutar mi aplicación.

Answer (score 1):

Yo tengo algún servidor funcionando con un entorno virtual creado para ese proyecto y en la configuración del apache queda algo como esto:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess nombre_proceso python-path=/var/www/carpeta_projecto:/var/www/carpeta_proyecto/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup nombre_proceso
WSGIScriptAlias / /ruta_hasta_e_wsgi.py/wsgi.py
```

Entre el link de la documentación oficial y otro que he encontrado en google, espero que te aporte información suficiente.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

http://pythonpiura.org/posts/2016/04/14/servir-aplicaciones-django-con-apache-y-mod_wsgi-en-centos-7/